# Bottom navigation view not working

Tags: android, fragment, bottomnavigationview

My bottom navigation view not working. When i click on items my fragment in not loading.

This is my activity for bottom navigation view

```
public static void enableNavigation(Context context, final BottomNavigationViewEx view, final FragmentManager supportFragmentManager){
    view.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment fragment;
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    fragment = new FragmentMarker();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_bookmark:
                    fragment = new FragmentBookmark();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_blog:
                    fragment = new FragmentBlog();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_notification:
                    fragment = new FragmentNotification();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
            }
           return false;
        }

        private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

 }
```

I`am using this library [link](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx)

Comment: Anything on log? If yes, put your log here

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
        Fragment fragment;
        boolean valToReturn = false
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_home:
                fragment = new FragmentMarker();
                valToReturn = true;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_bookmark:
                fragment = new FragmentBookmark();
                valToReturn = true;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_blog:
                fragment = new FragmentBlog();
                valToReturn = true;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_notification:
                fragment = new FragmentNotification();
                valToReturn = true;
                break;
       }
       loadFragment(fragment);
       return valToReturn;
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Java [**`break`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) is used to switch statement. It breaks the current flow
>   of the program at specified condition.

You miss to add **`break;`** .

**DEMO STRUCTURE**

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_home:
            fragment = FragmentMarker();
            loadFragment(fragment);
            break;

       case R.id.nav_bookmark:
            fragment = new FragmentBookmark();
            loadFragment(fragment);
            break;
          }
       .......
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a return instead of a break as long as the switch body is ending